# How to debug git clone error "ERROR GIT CLONE --stateless-rpc requires multi_ack_detailed"?

Tags: git, clone

I excute this command

```
git clone https://github.com/lakwarus/wordpress.git
```

Then I get a error:

```
fatal: --stateless-rpc requires multi_ack_detailed
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't know what this error is. How would you troubleshoot this?

Comment: It works fine for me... Maybe a temporary network error?

Answer (score 0):

Considering [GitHub status messages](https://status.github.com/messages) don't show any current issue, it is likely to be a connectivity issue on your side.

See for instance [this thread (2010)](http://listarc.com/showthread.php?59813-GIT%20Clone%20error) with the same error message.

You can try and see more details with

```
git clone --progress -v https://github.com/lakwarus/wordpress.git
```