# git clone produce --stateless-rpc requires multi_ack_detailed error

Tags: git, github

When i did following:

```
ubuntu@saucy1:~$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv ~/.rbenv
Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv'...
fatal: --stateless-rpc requires multi_ack_detailed
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What should i do? git clone any other repo produce same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247250

Comment: yes duplicate, because there are no any solution in previous question...

Answer (score 0):

The error message definitely is from some program called from the inards of `git clone`. To find out more, you could try running `strace(1)` to see what other programs are being called (and how) (look for `exec` calls), and dig down from there. Here (Fedora 20, but git from git) `git-clone` (the command ultimately called by `git clone`) is an executable, not a script.

If git is from a package for your operating system, and everything is up to date, perhaps yo should report it as a bug.

A farfetched reason I can imagine is that you need to log into the remote system via `ssh` or set up a HTTPS connection; if that fails (missing/wrong login/password, idiotic firewall blocks part of the transaction, ...) it might confuse some piece into erroring out.